# Unable to use Dependencies in a DigitalOcean FaaS

Tags: digital-ocean, faas

I've created a simple FaaS in DigitalOcean but it fails on the very first line. *I'm using the web interface* to remove as many variables as possible.

```js
NodeMailer = require('nodemailer');

// ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
```

So I try this with the following result:

```js
import NodeMailer from 'nodemailer';

// Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'nodemailer' imported from /tmp/index.mjs
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a function that has multiple files or contains dependencies **must** be done using the [CLI](https://docs.digitalocean.com/reference/doctl/reference/serverless/). The web interface is not capable since npm (or equivalent package manager) is required.

To start locally, install the Serverless package, then:

- `doctl serverless init <path/to/directory>`
- `doctl serverless watch <path/to/directory>` (Optional while developing)
- Or
- `doctl serverless deploy <path/to/directory>`